# Service client C++ tutorial simple question

Tags: ros, c++, tutorial, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a question about the code:

```
if (client.call(srv))
 {
   ROS_INFO("Sum: %ld", (long int)srv.response.sum);
 }
 else
 {
   ROS_ERROR("Failed to call service add_two_ints");
   return 1;
 }
```

Why is there a return value of 1? Is a return value just always required when calling a service?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215040/service-client-c++-tutorial-simple-question/) by [OmoNaija](https://answers.ros.org/users/23049/omonaija/) on ROS Answers with karma: 213 on 2015-07-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2015-08-01**:
You removed the function around your snippet, so we can only guess what the return value means. Is it the return value of your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The return value of `client.call(srv)`?

Then the return value is always 1 (true - boolean) when the service succeeded in calling it.
If for example the node for the service would have been stopped for any reason, the service would fail to call,
because it does not exist, then you should get a 0 (false).

---

The return value of the else statement?

The return value of the else statement would be for your node or a function, anything else than 1 would indicate another process/calling function checking your programs/functions return and see if it is not 0 that something went wrong with it.

0 normally indicates, all right, sometimes it is the other way round ...

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2